# Select specific div and get outerHeight with Angular's jqLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to rid my Webapp of jQuery and only use Angular's jqLite, since there isn't that much I need to do with jQuery anyway and I've read several times that using jQuery with AngularJS is not pretty.

My problem is that I need to select divs with specific id's, but jqLite only supports search by tag names as far as I can see. Furthermore, I need .outerHeight(), which also seems to be absent. So naturally, my current code doesn't work:

```
app.directive('contentMargin', function($document, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $document.ready(function() {
                var topMargin = elem.find('#header').outerHeight(true);
                var bottomMargin = elem.find('#nav').outerHeight(true);
                elem.find('#content').css({'margin-top':topMargin, 'margin-bottom':bottomMargin});
            });     
        }
    };
});
```

Here is where I use the directive:

```
<div id="wrapper" content-margin>

    <!---Header--->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo" class="fullwidth">
            <a href="#home"><img src="images/logo.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!---Content--->
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <!---Footer Nav--->
    <div id="nav" class="fullwidth" ng-controller="MainController">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        [...]
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this without full jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

mate, I suggest you use Vanilla JS, it's powerful than you thought...

the equivlent code in Vanilla Js is below:

```
function Dimension(elmID) {
var elmHeight, elmMargin, elm = document.getElementById(elmID);
if(document.all) {// IE
    elmHeight = elm.currentStyle.height;
    elmMargin = parseInt(elm.currentStyle.marginTop, 10) +    parseInt(elm.currentStyle.marginBottom, 10) + "px";
} else {// Mozilla
    elmHeight = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, '').getPropertyValue('height');
    elmMargin = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, '').getPropertyValue('margin-top')) + parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, '').getPropertyValue('margin-bottom')) + "px";
}
return (elmHeight+elmMargin);
}
```

In your case, your code looks like:

```
var topMargin = Dimension('header');
var bottomMargin = Dimension('nav');
```

I've read most of Jquery/Jquery UI source code, actually, they are just plain code, and sometimes you can do better than them. lol, happy coding bro!

Comment: Thank you, but my whole point with my question was that I'm trying to get away from extra js libraries and only using Angular's already build in jqLite. If it's not possible to achieve my requirements with jqLite, I can just stay with jQuery, since I already have working code for that.

Comment: "Vanilla JS" isn't a library. It refers to plain JavaScript.